# How to configure error logging at Source level in a Data Flow Task of SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

How to configure error logging at Source level in a Data Flow Task of SSIS?

Sample script used in the example.

```
create table test_data (col1 int, col2 varchar(100))

insert into test_data values (1, '00 0');
insert into test_data values (2, '02');
```

OLE DB Source SQL Command with following query

```
select * from test_data where col2=0;
```

This query fails

Destination is a flat file.

During execution following error is reported.

> OLE DB Source [1] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB
>   error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E07. An OLE DB record is
>   available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0" Hresult:
>   0x80040E07 Description: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar
>   value '00 0' to data type int.".

I am getting above error when I run the package.I know the query is not correct but I am not intended to change the source query, this is sample derived from my application.

In order to log this error to a LOG file by specifying a location, what I should do?

I tried using the error output but that handles the errors only on the data coming from Source but not with the query.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **PLEASE** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish with error logging? The trivial answer is to turn on Logging, select the OnError event and be done with it but that may not meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways by which you can log the Error .

1.You can use SSIS Logging feature .
SSIS->Logging

Select the Provider Type (SSIS Log Provider for Text File ) In case you want the error to be saved in text file .

```
    Go the Details tab and select OnError Event .
```

2.In the Event handler of the component Click the On Error Event and drag and drop a Script Task and write a code to  capture the error and save it to a text file .Use the System variable (**System::ErrorCode**) and 
(**System::ErrorDescription**) to get to know the Error information

Hope this helps.!